# Problem reading data from serial in ESP32

Tags: arduino, pic, uart, esp32

I´m triying to connect a PIC16F877A with an ESP32 on a LOLIND32 development board. The communication works fine when I try to send data form the ESP32 to the PIC but it doesn´t when I try the opposite thing. Can someone help me?

```
//ESP32 code (Arduino Framework) 
  char IN_MSG = 0;
  void setup() {
   pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
   Serial.begin(9600);
   Serial.println("Inciando comunicacion");
   Serial.print(TX);
   Serial.print(RX);
}
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() == 1) {
    IN_MSG = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(IN_MSG);
    if(Serial.read() == 0xAA){
    digitalWrite(5,LOW);
    }
    }
}

//PIC16F877A Code
#include <main.h>
#use rs232(baud=9600,parity=N,xmit=PIN_C5,rcv=PIN_C6,bits=8,stream=PORT1)
 void main()
 {
   while(TRUE)
   {
       putc(0xAA);
       delay_ms(1000);
}
```

Comment: does both of them working on the same voltage lvls?

Comment: Is the 'TRIS' register in the PIC correct?

Comment: A more precise description of "it does not work" would be helpful.  Are the words not received at all or not in the correct way? Is the returned result "constant" or varies for multiple tries? Furthermore UART uses two independent connections. That one is working properly does not imply that the other is good as well so checking the "non functional" connection might be worth it.